# Use object in included pug file, but returns list of objects instead

Tags: javascript, pug

I would like to loop through an object. This object is defined in a template called `testpage.pug`.

```
block vars
  -
    var testObject = [
      {id: '1', name: 'John'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Bert'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Fred'},
    ]

include ../_modules/testloop.pug
```

My goal is to loop through the object in the included `testloop.pug` file. And being able to use the values in that template as for example:

```
ul
  each test in #{testObject}
    li= test.name
```

But in this example, the `#testObject` isn't *loopable*. But I can return it. For example if I just run:

```
code.formattedDebug= #{testObject}
// output on page: <[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]>
```

So perhaps do you need to do something to this *Array of Objects* (or is it?) first to parse them?

I've consulted:

- https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html
- https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html
- <s>https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp</s>

Comment: `#{ }` is used to reference variables inside HTML text. Just use `each test in testObject` (and stay off w3schools, especially pages completely unrelated to your problem ;)

Comment: Thanks. But then it doesn't recognize the var somehow. In other words, it returns: *`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`* if used without `#{...}`.

Comment: And using `code.formattedDebug= JSON.stringify(testObject)` also returns results to the page. That's why I thought maybe something had to be stringified or something?

Comment: You need to make sure that the template that gets rendered includes both the `vars` block and the `ul`. So far it simply sounds like the `vars` block is missing. I tried your code and it worked on the spot.

Comment: Did you use the including of the `testloop.pug` file inside the other file `testpage/.pug`? And did you include or strip the `#{...}` part?

Comment: yes, exactly like you planned to. I put the `ul` in a block named `output`, added `extends layout` to `testpage.pug` and rendered using `layout.pug` (which displays the `var` and `output` blocks).